# A quote with multiple product sections

Tags: visualforce, opportunity-lineitem, quote, quotelineitem

I am attempting to customize a quote to include multiple products sections, for different categories of products.

Lets say that I am providing a quote for a home remodel. I want to have the kitchen quote items (tiles, granite, backsplash, etc) be its own product section, then have the basement remodel items be grouped in a separate section.

I'm not really sure the best way to approach this, I'm considering adding a product category field, then creating the different sections in a Visualforce page where I filter by the category field.  Not sure that will work out, or if that's the best way.

Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this type of customization? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar needs and spent some time working on the solution. We then found a very good app which works with standard Salesforce quote module. This apps allows us to do section based on any attribute and also summarize the info for each section. Here is the link if you want to install trial - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4AsxEAF

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this looks very helpful but I first want to try to do this without purchasing an app.